# En un código de C++ tipo cola, el nuevo elemento se inserta en el primer lugar de la cola

Tags: c++

Yo quiero colar a un amigo en mi cola y quiero coger la posición siguiente a la máxima ocupada y darle la información de la posición máxima, y luego la posición máxima darle la del lugar anterior. He escrito esto:

```
if(colaCitas->posicion<20){

            cout << "-----------------------" <<"\n\n";
            cout << "Introduzca los datos del paciente a colar:\n" <<"\n";
            cout << "-----------------------" <<"\n\n";

                cout << "DNI: "; cin >> usuario.dni;
                cout << "Nombre: "; cin >> usuario.nombre;
                cout << "Apellido 1: "; cin >> usuario.apellido1;
                cout << "Apellido 2: "; cin >> usuario.apellido2;
                cout << "Motivo de la cita: "; cin >> usuario.motivo;
                cout << "Tiempo de consulta: "; cin >> usuario.tiempoCita;

            cout << "-----------------------" << "\n\n";

        for (int i=colaCitas->posicion; i=1; i--){
                colaCitas->colaConsulta[i+1]=colaCitas->colaConsulta[i];
                colaCitas->colaConsulta[i]=colaCitas->colaConsulta[i-1];
            }
            
            colaCitas->posicion++;
            colaCitas->colaConsulta[0]=usuario;
            
            cout << "La cola se ha modificado correctamente.\n";

        }else{
            cout << "La cola esta llena. No se pueden introducir más citas.\n";
        }
```

Pero no me va, solo mete el nuevo usuario en el primer lugar de la cola. Y no entiendo por qué, leo que están bien puestos todos los puestos del array.

Answer (score 0):

El problema de tu código está en en el bucle `for`, si `colaCitas->posicion` es `1`, el contenido del bucle solo se ejecutará una vez. Si es distinto de `1`, no ejecutara nada. Te recuerdo la estructura de un bucle `for`:

```
for (inicialización; condición; instrucción post ejecución) {
    contenido del bucle;
}
```

No me queda claro si quieres colocar al nuevo usuario en el índice `0` del array ("empujando" a los otros elementos) o colocarlo al final del array.

En ambos casos debes tener cuidado de no pasarte del tamaño del array, ya que esto puede modificar la memoria y producir errores muy serios (para evitar esto puedes usar un contenedor dinámico como `std::vector`).

También seria útil que mostraras una mayor parte del código, ya que no se entienden ciertas cosas (declaraciones y definiciones de variables, clases, etc), que pueden ayudar a entender mejor el funcionamiento del programa y a resolver el problema.

Por ultimo aclarar que es el inicio y el final de la cola, ya que lo que tengo entendido como inicio es `array[0]` y como final `array[indice_mas_alto]`, pero no sé como lo implementaste.

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu ayuda! <3

Comment: @AlisonCastle, si la respuesta solventó la duda, márcala como solución pulsando en el tic